# guessing game while loop not looping

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool play_game(int n) {
    int guess;
    bool noguesses = false;
    int numofguesses = 0;
    cout << "Welcome to my number guessing game\n";
    while (n!=guess && !noguesses)
    {
        if (numofguesses < 6)
        {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Enter your guess: ";
            cin >> guess;
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "You entered: " << guess;
            numofguesses++;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            oog = true;
        }
    }
    if (noguesses) {
        cout << "I'm sorry. You didn't find my number.\n";
        cout << "It was" << n << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "You found it in" << numofguesses << "guess(es)\n";
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int secretnum = 5;
    play_game(secretnum);
}
```

When I run this, the program stops after `cout << "You entered: " << guess;`. I want it to keep looping until the number of guesses reaches 6, or until the user inputs the correct answer.

Comment: The function ends because you return from it. `return false;` If you don't want it to end don't return.

Comment: Also `oog` has no reference.

Comment: ... and `guess` is initially indeterminate on first-evaluation of `n != guess` in the while-loop condition, and therefore invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `return false;`

```
if (numofguesses < 6)
{
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Enter your guess: ";
    cin >> guess;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "You entered: " << guess;
    numofguesses++;
    return false;  //Remove this line
}
```